# Error creating xercesc dom parser object

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an Xercesc DOM Parser in my code and for some reason and try to instiate an XercescDOM object I get a NULL pointer returned. I am using xercesc version 2.8
Here the code.

```
using namespace xercesc;
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
try
{
    XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
}
catch (const XMLException& e) 
{
    char* errMsg = XMLString::transcode(e.getMessage());
    cout << "Problem initializing parser: " << errMsg;
    XMLString::release(&errMsg);
}

XercesDOMParser* parser = new XercesDOMParser();
if (!parser)
    cout << "Failed to create parser";
}
```

Comment: "New" never returns null in newer C++ implementations. The only reason to get NULL from new is when there is no memory, and in newer C++ it's handled with exception. Dis Xerces overload "new" for that class? Very suspicious. What compiler you're using?

Answer (score 1):

@Doug: no, this is not related, afaik, because the code you linked to tries to fetch the document from the parse() method, but this is a [void function](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classAbstractDOMParser.html#c0b30b3d2116c488920646f0d700d9f0), so the result will always be "null" this way.

Otherwise, I don't see any problem with the parent post. It compiles almost ok and here I have a correct result (non-null parser).

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug some where else in my code.